# Calling a web service without using soap

Tags: .net, web-services

How can I call a web service directly without using soap?

I basically want to use the web service like a class library and have the same performance as if it was a class library.

The code I am calling is in the same project as the web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to call the code behind a webservice without going through the service itself, then you need to refactor that code out into a reusable library that the service (and your code) can both reference.